# Why does required="true" not fail validation when disabled="true" is specified

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

```
<a4j:outputPanel id="tapalSectionSendToPanel" ajaxsingle="true">
    <h:inputText id="sendToId1"  value="#{MainBean.SectionBean.sendTo}" 
        class="createresizedTextbox" 
        required="true" requiredMessage="#{msg.labl_required}"
        disabled="true" />
 <h:message for="sendToId1" style="color:red" />
</a4j:outputPanel>
```

i need to validate textbox for empty validation and should show required when i click button without entering any value in textbox. It works fine without  `disabled="true"`. Whats the alternative for my requirement.

Comment: You have conflicting requirements: `disabled="true"` will not allow the user to enter any value and it'll be ignored for anything else than display. So, why do you want to attach a validator here?

Comment: Also, you have several invalid attributes in your JSF: `autosubmit`, `showRequired`, `requiredMessage` won't do anything here and `class` should probably be `styleClass`.

Comment: i have removed the validator and whats the problem with my jsf

Comment: You can't "test" this. Either the user is allowed to change the value, then remove the `disabled="true"`. Or you are just displaying a (already set) value to the user, then the `required="true"` is pointless. You can just show the text you want in that case (use  `rendered="#{empty MainBean.SectionBean.sendTo}"` for this text).

Comment: i have a rich:treenode with set of usernames and by clicking on it populates the name in this textbox ,which is the username to send message for particular username and hence without clicking the treenode i must raise message for the user to select username and hence i want validator

Comment: CanadaPost, for example, offers a service called AddressComplete. This service auto-populates City, Province, and Postal Code fields based on the first line of a given address. Thus the latter fields must be disabled (to reduce typographical errors), but values are still required. Re-using the existing validation against those fields would be a single line of JSF code. These are edge cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`disabled="true"` disables the input (so it's skipped when the form is submitted), if you don't want the user to type in it use `readonly="readonly"`

Answer (score 4):

First, `required` and `disabled` don't go well together, because they are mutually exclusive as per the [JSF Spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/index.html):

- **required**: Flag indicating that the user is required to provide a submitted value for this input component.
- **disabled**: Flag indicating that this element must never receive focus or be included in a subsequent submit.

Like I said in the comments, you can just display a message when the user tries to submit the form without selecting a node:

```
<h:inputText id="sendToId1"  value="#{MainBean.SectionBean.sendTo}" 
    styleClass="createresizedTextbox" required="true" readonly="true" />
<h:message for="sendToId1" value="#{msg.labl_required}" 
    rendered="#{facesContext.postback and facesContext.validationFailed}" />
```

As an alternative you can just display a text anywhere in your markup:

```
<h:outputText value="#{msg.labl_required}" 
    rendered="#{empty MainBean.SectionBean.sendTo}" />
```